# Mysql server has gone away mysqldump and scp

Tags: database, linux, mysql, scp

I am trying to copy over a large database from one server to the next without using `mysqldump` to copy the data and changing the name of the `DB` on the new server.

I am using `mysqldump` to copy the database structure and than using `SCP` to copy the data itself. I can verify the database structure after I do the dump but when I copy the data over and try to show tables or do anything else I get this:

> mysql> show tables;
>
> ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
>
> No connection. Trying to reconnect...
>
> Connection id:    1
>
> Current database: jabba_2
>
> ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
>
> No connection. Trying to reconnect...
>
> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)
>
> ERROR: Can't connect to the server

Here are the commands I'm using:

```
mysqldump -d -u root -pXXXX DB_1 | mysql -h sever_b -u root -pXXXX DB_2

scp -i ssh.key -r /opt/mysql/db_1 root@server_b:/opt/mysql/db_2 && ssh -i ssh.key

root@server_b chown -R mysql.mysql /opt/mysql/db_2
```

The database is about `31G`.
I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: look here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174/how-can-i-move-a-database-from-one-server-to-another

Comment: Check /var/log/mysql , maybe there are worser things, too...

Comment: Doing that now. I'm not sure what's wrong with this method though?

Comment: Now if I just copy the data itself, just using scp/rsync then when I do SELECT * FROM table_name it says table does not exist. But doing show tables works. I've copied the innodb files over as well

Comment: I was using the script one of the users posted in that thread but for some reason the SELECT * part lists the files in my directory and I don't know why.